# iReport preview/exporter output not handling UTF-8 translations?

Tags: utf-8, internationalization, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm trying to make my reports work with a translations bundle. No matter what I try, I can't seem to render UTF-8 for any language - I just get two broken characters for every UTF-8 character.

My report starts with this: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
...but iReport preview doesn't work,

and my actual code has this:

```
JRProperties.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.encoding", "UTF-8");
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING, "UTF-8")
```

Neither seems to be able to output UTF-8. What could possibly be going on here? I'm pulling my hair out. Even with the font set to `Arial`, I'm having issues. My web-app is using the same font and similar bundles with Grails, and I have no issues there, so something is happening specific to jasperreports.

**EDIT:**
I thought byte order markers may have been the issue, but it isn't. I've created a basic report that shows the failure in 4.0.2.

Here's the resource bundle:

[image: Greek properties file]

And the output in iReport:

[image]

And here's the [report](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5142994/stackoverflow/report1.jrxml), and the [properties](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5142994/stackoverflow/report.properties) file used to observe these results.

**Nore information:**
When the properties files are saved in ANSI encoding, I can get all german characters, including ä and ß. When the properties files are saved as UTF-8, only ASCII characters work.

Comment: This is weird. Does this happen with labels in your Column Header or just with data you get from a DB?

Comment: This happens with all static text. I'm not pulling *any* text from the database.

Comment: Could it be an OS issue? I've been using iReport with Greek UTF-8 letters for years without any problem. I would reinstall it.

Comment: I get the same issue when running on a server. I'm using 4.0.2. Fails on CentOS and Windows 7. I'm going to try and create the smallest-possible-project failure tomorrow, and then maybe I can attach a project to the question that illustrates the base case failure.

Comment: I don’t understand why you mentioned a font. That has nothing to do with your output bit pattern.

Comment: @tchrist: The font could have not supported Unicode. Arial does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stefan, I know that it is not very good solution, but it works for your sample.

```
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="49" y="0" width="359" height="38"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Arial" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new String($R{title}.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8")]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

In case you know source codepage the convertation will help you. May be you can pass codepage in report and use it as parameter or variable in expression.

The expression can be like this:

```
   <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new String($R{title}.getBytes($P{codePage}), "UTF-8")]]></textFieldExpression>
```

or like this, if you can pass codepage in header of your properties file:

```
   <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new String($R{title}.getBytes($R{codePage}), "UTF-8")]]></textFieldExpression>
```

**UPDATE:**
After adding Arial font my irfonts.xml (%IREPORT_DIR%\ireport\fonts) has this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<fontFamilies>
   <fontFamily name="Arial">
       <normal><![CDATA[arial.ttf]]></normal>
       <bold><![CDATA[arialbd.ttf]]></bold>
       <italic><![CDATA[ariali.ttf]]></italic>
       <boldItalic><![CDATA[arialbi.ttf]]></boldItalic>
       <pdfEncoding><![CDATA[Identity-H]]></pdfEncoding>
       <pdfEmbedded><![CDATA[false]]></pdfEmbedded>
   </fontFamily>

</fontFamilies>
```

Comment: By codepage, do you mean the encoding of the properties files? They should be UTF-8, but I guess I can triple check. At this point, "good" solutions are not an issue. I just need solutions, lol. I'll try this method regardless on Monday.

Comment: @Stefan I check your propertie file - my editor (Notepad++) detects the codepage like "ANSI as UTF-8" (==UTF-8 without BOM, Byte Order Mark). I tried convertation from CP-1252 to UTF-8 and it works

Comment: I tried this same conversion, and it's still failing. The file is valid UTF-8, so I don't see why the conversion would be needed anyway.

Comment: Wrong text, no exceptions. I get more garbled text, just not what I posted above.

Comment: @Stefan. Try this: new String($R{title}.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8")

Comment: Well, this works for Greek, German, and a couple other easy languages, but it's breaking on Japanese, Chinese, and Korean. The properties files do lookt o be UTF-8 encoded, so why would this parsing be necessary?

Comment: I think that JR debugging is needed to answer your question. May be this is the bug of source code - the part which reads data from properties file.

Comment: Actually, this looks like it works for web output for korean and japanese, but PDF output is broken even with PDF embed enabled.

Comment: @Stefan And what about iReport internal viewer?

Comment: iReport internal viewer just shows squares. Whenever I try to export to PDF, I get this:

Error exporting print... Could not load the following font :  pdfFontName   : Times-Roman pdfEncoding   : Identity-H isPdfEmbedded : true 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not load the following font :  pdfFontName   : Times-Roman pdfEncoding   : Identity-H isPdfEmbedded : true

Comment: I've added arial font for my iReport via Tools-Options-iReport-Fonts. <font fontName="Arial" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>

Comment: Can I see your configuration for that? I've added the font, but I get the same error for Arial.

Comment: Regardless, this gets me to HTML and XLS, which is better than before. This PDF issue is likely a separate matter altogether.

Comment: @Stefan I've updated my answer - added info about font and updated font declaration for text element

Comment: @Stefan I've added link to msdn resource with info about fonts: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688134. The quote from article: The Windows core fonts (Times New Roman, Courier New, Arial, Microsoft Sans Serif, and Tahoma) contain Latin, Hebrew, Arabic, Greek, and Cyrillic scripts but do not contain East Asian script characters. Another useful link: http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/fonts-east-asian.html

Comment: Ah, of course! You really earned that bounty. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer for other developer which also have encoding problem when generating reports...

I had a similar problem when generating reports with, for example, French locale.
My bundles and templates files are stored in a database to allow new templates and locale without recompiling the project. 
BUT every characters with accents contains in the French bundle aren't print correctly.
So, I :

- Check the bundle char encoding (set to UTF-8 without BOM)
- Check the XML header of the .jrxml report file ()

I think jasper reports take UTF-8 by default to generate reports but I'm not sure at 100%.
It can be forced with :

```
JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
```

The problem persist again so instead of :

```
ResourceBundle bundle = new PropertyResourceBundle(new ByteArrayInputStream(myBundle)); // myBundle is a byte array retrieve from a DB
```

I do this :

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(myBundle), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
ResourceBundle bundle = new PropertyResourceBundle(reader);
```

After that, just passing the resource bundle to the JasperFillManager and every thing goes well now.
May be it's so simple but it would have saved me 2 or 3 hours of research...

Comment: For me, it was enough to do as Sébastien Vanmechelen said: `InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(myBundle), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
ResourceBundle bundle = new PropertyResourceBundle(reader);` My properties file is UTF-8 without BOM (use notepad++) encoded to do not have problemas with Maven filtering (it needs UTF-8 files).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your resource bundles don't have a [byte order marker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). This will break jasperreports, and it won't show up in IDEs or text editors.